# Touch bar and/or Catalina seems to make the keyboard unresponsive

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, catalina, touch-bar

I have a MacBook Pro 15-inch 2019.  In various apps, the keyboard *seems* to be unresponsive, but I’m not sure why.  In other apps (like Slack, for example), the keyboard works perfectly.  I think it’s got something to do w/ the touch bar?  When I use a docking-adapter, and connect an external keyboard, mouse, and monitor, I’m able to type on it fine; no matter which app I’m in.  Is this a known issue?  Also, I upgraded to Catalina about a week ago, so I'm wondering if that's an issue as well?

Note - I was only able to type this by typing in Slack, and then pasting into the Question field; I couldn’t type directly into the field on the Ask Different website.

Comment: Wondering if this is related? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250716705

Comment: Here's an odd one. Some people have been complaining that after updating to macOS Catalina, the keyboards of their MacBooks no longer work.

Luckily, there's quite an easy fix. Restart the MacBook, and once macOS Catalina has loaded, close the lid of the MacBook for a few seconds. Then, open it back up, and the keyboard should begin working again.

Hopefully Apple releases a fix for this bug soon – but at least it's relatively easy to get around for now.